# How to color duplicate cell groups with different color?

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

column A has:

```
table
pencil
table
table
paper
pencil
paper
```

so, all cells containing `table` should have yellow color, `pencil` should have blue, and `paper` should have red color,

How to do this?

Comment: Conditional formatting? You'll have to create one rule for each criterion.

Comment: isnt there an easier way?

Comment: Maybe a VBA solution, but I'm not familiar with coding in VBA :( I have no idea for a single rule for this.

Comment: Use conditional formatting per Jerry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your input range the name "Argument"

create another range "Template" where you list each element once and format it in the way you like (borders, styles, background colors etc. ...)

run the following code

```
Sub FormatFromList()
Dim ArgCell As Range, TemplateCell As Range

    For Each ArgCell In Range("Argument").Cells
        For Each TemplateCell In Range("Template").Cells
            If ArgCell = TemplateCell Then
                TemplateCell.Copy
                ArgCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Exit For
            End If
        Next TemplateCell
    Next ArgCell
End Sub
```

If you want more automation, think of using a `Worksheet_Change(...)` trigger to call `FormatFromList()`

Comment: oops ... that's not the latest version of my code, sorry ... updated ... yes it could be simplified, but I like to see in the code what I'm doing ... call it personal style :)

Comment: whoowww ... receiving a downvote after nearly 4 years ... would be curious to know a reason